# The Blank Sudoku

Tags: logical-deduction, visual, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

---

(h/t to Beastly Gerbil, whose [1,2,3... Trinary!!!](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106499) puzzle provided inspiration for this puzzle)

This puzzle is a normal Sudoku, with each digit from 1-9 appearing once per row and column, and once in each square. The variation is in the clues; each clue is a consecutive substring of the Roman numeral expansion of the digit in the cell. There's no funny business: the Roman numeral for 4 is only IV, not IIII, and the substrings are given in order. As an example the clue "VI" cannot represent 4, but could represent 6, 7, or 8. I hope you enjoy!

[image]

**TEXT VERSION**

```
═════════════════════════════════════
║   |I I|   ║ V | V |   ║I V|   |I I║
-------------------------------------
║III|   |I I║V I|   |   ║I I|I I|   ║
-------------------------------------
║V I| V |   ║   |I I|   ║   |III| V ║
═════════════════════════════════════
║ X |   | V ║   |   | V ║   |I I|VII║
-------------------------------------
║   |   |V I║   |I I| V ║   | X |   ║
-------------------------------------
║I I|   |   ║ X |   | V ║ V |   |I I║
═════════════════════════════════════
║III|   |   ║ I | I |I I║ V |   |   ║
-------------------------------------
║ V |   |VII║ I |   | X ║ V |   | V ║
-------------------------------------
║VII|   | V ║III|I I|III║ V | V |   ║
═════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: I won't have time to solve this, but for any who can here's a [Penpa link](https://git.io/JtIIb).

Comment: Also, does "consecutive substring" mean a substring at any point in the numeral? So can both "V" and "I", as well as "IV", be in a cell that has a 4?

Comment: @bobble: Yes, it is a substring that may begin and end at any point of the numeral. So the digit 4 could be in a square labelled "I", "V", or "IV".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Solution (click to see large version):

> [image]

The first thing is to produce the following list:

```
I:    1234 6789
II:    23   78
III:    3    8
IV:      4
V:       45678
VI:        678
VII:        78
X:            9
```

From that, standard Sudoku techniques apply. I'll just list some middle steps below.

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

> [image]

Comment: That is the correct answer!

Comment: I found a very useful tip is to add to the roman numerals when possible.  For example if you have deduced that a certain cell can only be either a 7 or an 8, make the roman numeral in the corner into a VII.