# Shattered Webs - SS#3

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the third puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

---

[image]

---

**Time to switch up the grid a bit! Now we have a shattered web of clues and digits, see if you piece the web together!**

---

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bv_TrQwVFmMm-a4Q87qohpAknfsrhMMJarrd2GJ9Lac/edit?usp=sharing)

**RULES**:

- Normal sudoku rules apply, except instead of boxes there are irregular shaped regions
- There are only 8 numbers, 1-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Repeatedly iterating over the boxes (regions?) gave me:

> [image]

Then, doing the same over the columns gave me:

> [image]

All in all, this was a great puzzle! The gaps in the board made it a little tricky to keep track of how some numbers blocked certain spaces, but it was still very enjoyable. Looking forward to more of the series! :) This was a pretty straightforward solve, but if more reasoning or steps are needed, I can try to run through exactly what I did.

Comment: Good job again! Again, this wasn't a particularly hard one, just more a bit of fun. Off the top of my head, 6, 8 and 10 are the 'harder' ones, with 8 and 10 much more so than the others, but some of the others might also be a little tricky. (Also, if you click on the picture it will take you to a a copy of the puzzle with none of the background, so you wont have to screenshot) Good solve!