# This is an Odd Sudoku - SS#4

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the fourth puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

---

[image]

---

**Digits aren't enough... let's give a different type of clue!**

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/12aXU72gydFrVuq4o8zXfIR31-HdKeFrXWNfZrynFjSE/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**RULES**:

- Normal Sudoku Rules apply
- Cells highlighted grey **must** contain an odd number

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution:

> [image]

Here's the process for solving:

> First, we saw that the only number that could be in the top row middle square was a 9, because all the other odd numbers were already in that column. The 6 slotted in easily after, because the middle square already had a 6. The middle and middle-right 8's followed suit because of process of elimination (they couldn't be in any grey squares.) That left only a 2 to finish the middle column.

(Image below)

> [image]

Next:

> The right side filled out fairly easily because the middle row had 5 grey squares, meaning that each of them had to be odd, and each of the white squares had to be even. That allowed us to fill in the top right square and eliminate many of the other top row and right column numbers to be one of just a couple.

(Image below)

> [image]

Next:

> From here, the puzzle fell together pretty straightforwardly. Narrowing down those rows and columns from the previous image allowed us to narrow many of the grey squares down to just one or two numbers which, through process of elimination, gave us many of the even numbers across the top and bottom corners. From there, it was just hunting for the next straightforward "there's only one possibility left" over and over until the grid was filled. (Please let me know if you need further explanation, though! Really fun sudoku!

(Image below)

> [image]

Comment: Sniped! Great to see you around again, kristinalustig :-)

Comment: Hi @JeremyDover! Once I solved it I was writing it up so fast, I was so sure someone was gonna snipe me. :P

Comment: Great solve! That’s plenty of explanation, once you got to a certain point with almost all sudokus, it because very straightforward, but you explained the difficult bits nicely! This is one of my favourite ‘wacky’ sudokus as it brings some nice new logic into play with the odds and even restrictions, so glad you enjoyed!