# Sudoku... with 10 digits? SS#6

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the sixth puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

(Added a notice about an upcoming bounty to SS#1)

I also accidentally posted puzzle 6 yesterday, so puzzle 5 and 6 are swapping.

---

[image]

---

**0 was feeling left out and wanted to join in with the fun...**

---

**RULES**:

- Normal sudoku rules apply
- There is an extra digit, 0, in all rows, columns and boxes
- One cell in each row, column and box is split to hold 2 digits

Good luck!

Comment: Congratulations, you made sudoku more complete-cated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting by going through each box from top to bottom, then left to right:

> [image: first iteration of extra digit sudoku]

Repeating the process:

> A lot of hidden singles later, we get:
>  [image: final solution to extra digit sudoku]

Thanks for another fun solve!

Comment: Yup! This is probably the easiest out of the 14, wasn't expecting it last that long. Its surprisingly difficult to make this hard, theres just too much extra information :P We're approaching the heavy hitters now, some more challenging puzzles incoming