# A Scrumptious Sudoku Sandwich - SS#7

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the seventh puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

Halfway through now! The puzzles so far have been somewhat of an introduction to these wacky sudokus, time to start stepping it up a notch! The next puzzles are going to be harder, not all the same difficulty, but all just as wacky!

---

[image]

---

**Mmmmmm... nothing tastier than a bit of 2-8 between two slices of 1 and 9**

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rhYhQvXbmgV9_3jmd-SSU_d0RgOb_aedWPtBCKSb_fg/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**RULES**

- Normal Sudoku rules apply
- The numbers on the outside of the grid show the sum of the digits 'sandwiched' between 1 and 9

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, let's take a look at the rows and columns with 0s

> They must have the 1 and 9 right next to each other. We can actually determine the exact placements of the 1 and 9 for each. In C5 and R6 one side of the existing 1 is blocked. In C1 and R9 one side of the existing 9 can't have a 1 because of sudoku rules. In C8 the 9 must now go in the bottom-right 3x3 box, and there is only one way to fit a 1 near it without contradicting row clues.
>  [image: step 1]

Now,

> I got to here with plain "This is the only place for <number> to go in this box/row/column" logic.
>  [image: step 2]

Let's use the top-edge clues once again!

> From left to right: The 1 in C3 must go on the top, so that all of 2-8 (summing to 35) can sandwich between 1 and 9. The only way to sandwich a 4 in C4 is to sandwich a single 4, and there is only room for that to happen in one way. The 9 in C7 must be the bottom of the sandwich as below it sums to more than 6. The sandwich must use the 2 above; the only way for a sum of 6 is 2+4 so that can be placed. In C9 there is already a sum of 13 below the 9, and a 1 will finish that sandwich.
>  [image: step 3]

After that,

> Another round of plain "This is the only place for <number> to go in this box/row/column" logic.
>  [image: step 4]

Now to use the left-edge clues

> From top to bottom: R1 has a sum of 11 to one side of the 1 which can be safely sandwiched away. The 9 in R3 must be on the left side of the 1 to allow for a large enough sandwich, and there is only one spot that it can be placed due to sudoku logic. Both the 1 and 9 in R7 are there, and the sum of 10 can be completed as 6+4.
>  [image: step 5]

To wrap it all up,

> The rest of the sudoku can now be completed with "This is the only place for <number> to go in this box/row/column" logic.
>  [image: complete solution]