# A 7x7 Suguru - SS#9

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the ninth puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

This might not technically count as a 'sudoku', but some of the rules are the same so I've included it.

---

[image]

---

**I guess the numbers don't get along well with themselves...**

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iXkAMLxmObwY4kCY1FPobnuG2ySfPqflyjVGW3RskfQ/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**RULES**:

- Fill in every box so each box contains the digits from 1 to n, where n is the number of cells in the box

  - So a box with 4 cells, must contain the digits 1, 2, 3 and 4
- The same digit cannot be orthogonally or diagonally adjacent.

I really like these and I don't know if they've been seen on the site before. I might make an extra large one (and perhaps even wackier!) if people like this!

Comment: How are you making these great puzzles so fast?

Comment: @Anonymous I started making them a month in advance because I knew the FTC was coming :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I used the exact same logic for each picture here:

> Placing a number in a given region because there is only one spot for it to go; all other cells in that region are either already taken or are adjacent to other copies of that number.

With that in mind, some pictures, in order. I mostly completed two regions per picture.

Step 1:

> [image: step 1]
>  I started with the obvious single-cell region and placed a 1. I got a lot of more 1s.

Step 2:

> [image: step 2]
>  Now the top-right area.

Step 3:

> [image: step 3]
>  Now some lower-right areas.

Step 4:

> [image: step 4]
>  Finishing up the right side and some bottom area.

Step 5:

> [image: step 5]
>  Now working on the left side.

Step 6 (and the solution):

> [image: step 6]
>  With the top we're done!

Not hard but quite enjoyable.