# This Sudoku takes a step up! - SS#11

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the eleventh puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

---

[image]

---

**Can you ascend this puzzle and reach the top?**

[Google Sheets Link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1mD5oqOPlkq2AMzAW-UDeWBJ3IlXTIHZOgQa3oMSw6XY/edit?usp=sharing)

---

**RULES**:

- Normal Sudoku rules apply
- There are gaps in the grid, these do not 'block' a row or column in any way, and get jumped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Final solution:

> [image: final board]

> Starting simple by filling in most 2s and 4s
>  [image: step 1]

> Filling in the left column of boxes from completing boxes, hidden singles, and one row and one column
>  [image: step 2]

> Some more box, row, and column completion
>  [image: step 3]

> From this to the final solution is pretty trivial:
>  [image: final board]

Comment: Yup! This was a very easy one, it was hard to make it difficult as it’s almost a normal sudoku. Final three coming  soon, and they should all be a bit more interesting :)