# A Final Digitial Sudoku! - SS#14

Tags: logical-deduction, grid-deduction, sudoku

<sup>An entry in [Fortnightly Topic Challenge #47: "Wacky Sudokus"](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7139/fortnightly-topic-challenge-47-wacky-sudokus)</sup>

[Other puzzles in this series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A18250+%5Bsudoku%5D+title%3A%22SS%23%22)

---

---

Welcome to the final puzzle in this series! For more information about the series, [see the first puzzle and the introduction](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/106461/the-blind-killer-a-new-series-ss1). Enjoy!

---

[image]

---

**A Sudoku of the Digital Era!!**

---

**RULES**:

- Normal Sudoku Rules apply
- Some clues are partially given. The red 'numbers' show some of a digital number. The correct entry must be achievable with the highlighted segments in the seven segment display

For reference, here are the numbers in seven segment display:

[image]

---

This is the final sudoku in this series, hopefully everyone has enjoyed!!

I've had many new ideas and learnt a lot from the feedback on the puzzles, and will use it in the future for any new puzzles I make!

Good luck, and thanks for the positive feedback so far!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Converting the partial numbers to notes:

> [image: notes]

Filling in numbers based on notes:

> [image: numbers from notes]

Iterating through rows:

> [image: final solution]

Thanks @BeastlyGerbil for this fun series!

Comment: Wow that was quick! I didn't expect this to be solved quite this quickly, though I probably could have made this harder. Glad you enjoyed! I'll be planning some bigger but similar things in the future :)